# Can I send mail to users from nodejs contact page using nodemailer?

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

Is it possible to send messages to the usere from my gmail account using nodemailer in my Nodejs website?

Answer (score 0):

Yes... it's possible. If you are a beginner, then I would request you to follow the official docs for complete assistance.

**https://nodemailer.com/about/**